# Laravel Cashier: Trouble Updating Card (Fatal Error)

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-5

I've installed Laravel Cashier (v3.0.4) in my project and am at the point of allowing users to update their credit cards, but am running into issues when I attempt to do so. Here's the relevant pieces from my controller that handles it:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->user = Auth::user();
}

/**
 * Update credit card
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
public function updateCardPost() {
    $this->user->updateCard(Input::get('stripe-token'));

    session()->flash('flash_message', 'You have updated your credit card');
    return redirect()->route('dashboard.index');
}
```

I've verified the sanity-check items:

1. Actually posts to this controller
2. Successfully passing in token

But every time I try submit it, I'm getting an error in Cashier itself:

```
FatalErrorException in StripeGateway.php line 454:
Call to a member function create() on null
```

I've looked into this and it looks like it's passing the `$token` to the following: `$card = $customer->cards->create(['card' => $token]);`

So, I then did another sanity check by `dd($token)` in that method and that returns exactly what my form is supplying. It doesn't look like this block has changed much recently -- but there were some PSR-2 and one-off purchase updates; neither of which appear to have anything to do with what's going on here. So I'm at my whits-end on what's up here, but any clues would be a huge help. Thanks!

## Update

Have verified running `dd($customer->cards)` inside of the `updateCard()` method returns null -- probably because it's not ever saving the last four to the database when creating the subscription. Struggling to see how I can create a subscription (verified on Stripe), cancel and resume, yet my card details are not being updated locally, nor can I swap cards.

I used https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iPaKX7aPczQ as inspiration for how simple it "should be" to do this, with success on that end, but not mine.

## Update 2

Here's my entire User controller and Coffee implementation if it helps:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;
use Laravel\Cashier\Billable;
use Laravel\Cashier\Contracts\Billable as BillableContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract, BillableContract {

    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword, Billable;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * Laravel Cashier
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = ['trial_ends_at', 'subscription_ends_at'];

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'email',
        'password',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'phone',
        'biography',
        'twitter',
        'facebook',
        'linkedin'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    /**
     * A user can have many listings
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function listings() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Dashboard\Listing');
    }
}
```

Stripe.coffee

```
(($) ->
  'use strict'

  StripeBilling =
    init: ->
      @form = $('.js-subscription__create')
      @submitButton = @form.find '.js-subscription__create__submit'
      @submitButtonText = @submitButton.text()

      stripeKey = $('meta[name="publishable_key"]').attr 'content'
      Stripe.setPublishableKey stripeKey

      @bindEvents()
      return

    bindEvents: ->
      @form.on('submit', $.proxy(@sendToken, @))
      return

    sendToken: (event) ->
      event.preventDefault()
      @submitButton.attr("disabled", true).text 'One Moment'

      Stripe.createToken(@form, $.proxy(@stripeResponseHandler, @))
      return

    stripeResponseHandler: (status, response) ->
      if response.error
        @form.find('.js-form__errors').removeClass("uk-hidden").text response.error.message
        return @submitButton.text(@submitButtonText).attr('disabled', false)

      $('<input>'
        type: 'hidden'
        name: 'stripe-token'
        value: response.id
      ).appendTo @form

      @form[0].submit()
      return

  StripeBilling.init()

  return
) jQuery
```

Comment: Well, the error is pretty obvious:  `cards` public property must be an **instance of some class** , but for some reason it hasn't been instantiated. Probably you should look inside that class and see when and depending on which condition `cards` property is being instantiated? I.e you need to catch that moment, so that it would be much easier to handle that issue.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @bad_boy -- the tricky part here is that `cards` is accessed via a magic method, so I'm having a bit of trouble tracking that down.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a bug you should report. The code that's causing your error (in the cashier library) is poorly tested and just looks incorrect.

Comment: The repo doesn't have issues enabled (only PRs) so trying a different channel that may be able to shed some light.

Comment: Created a PR for part of the problem: https://github.com/laravel/cashier/pull/144 Still an issue with retrieving the last four as the customer object does not return the card information anymore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's due to an API change on Stripe's end. If you look at their [changelog](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2015-02-18) you'll notice that the "cards" attribute was changed to "sources" fairly recently.

**UPDATE**

You can choose the API Version that Stripe's own PHP framework is using with the following static method:

```
Stripe::setApiVersion("2015-02-10");
```

(That version number worked for me, but it could be that we need an older version.)

Comment: Thanks! While the answer certainly isn't downgrading your API version (as things should be up to date), I did submit a PR to get "part" of the problem resolved https://github.com/laravel/cashier/pull/144